# Spawning lot of Qthread makes gui hang

Tags: qt, user-interface, freeze, qthread

I need to spawn a lot of instances of `QThread`s which periodically process some data in a loop. So i start them all from `QMainWindow`. But when i start about 200-300 of them, depends on machine, i get the gui freeze for a minute. Im not wanting this kind of behaviour, what is can be done to avoid this? Is it practicale to make a qthread and class object in gui thread, then put them in a list, and start them all from `QFuture` or from `QThreadPool`, something like that? :

```
 MyClass * obj = new Myclass(id);
 QThread * thread = new QThread();
 obj->moveToThread(thread);
 connect(obj,SIGNAL(logData(QString)),this,SLOT(dataToListView(QString));
 list->append(thread);

 taskStartAllThreads * task = new taskStartAllThreads();
 task->setProxyList(list);

 QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(task);
 // later in QThreadPool task
     class taskStartAllThreads : public QObject,public QRunnable
     {
        Q_OBJECT
        public:
         void setProxyList(QList<QThread*> * list){
            m_threads = list;
         }
        protected:

        void run(){
            foreach(QThread* thread,m_threads)
                thread->start();
        }
        signals:
           void finished(); 
        private:
           QList<QThread*> * m_threads;
    };
```

Im not sure if that is right solution, does someone know the better solution to avoid gui freezing on lots of thread start.

Comment: You could move your startup "slow-task" to another thread which itself then starts up all the other threads off the Main Thread. Or you can look at QtConcurrent to do this....

Comment: @code_fodder so then i will need to reconnect all the signals right? Because i already tried to move in a thread pool as i did in the the main post, and the signals won't get emmited to the mainwindow which is very frustrating

Comment: That is a *very* large number of threads. I smell an X-Y problem.

Comment: @JonHarper what is x-y problem

Comment: See here: [What is the XY Problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @JonHarper but what is the solution then

Comment: @JonHarper not to start that much threads?

Comment: Find a way to avoid the overhead of starting so many threads. You need to do work on hardware that can't run that many threads *at one time*. How do you reduce the number of threads, and consequently, the overhead of those threads (as well as the massive cost of context switching them once they finally start)?

Comment: The GUI hang during startup is, therefore, simply symptomatic of a larger issue in your approach/design. Threads have a cost in memory, startup time, and in switching between them. Avoid using more than are necessary.